# Issue saving Vowpal Wabbit model to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, vowpalwabbit

I'm trying to save a learned VW model using the Python wrapper to an S3 bucket but am getting a Runtime Error.

Code is:

```
# directory
model_dir_test = f"s3://{bucket}/{model_dir}"


# model
vw = pyvw.vw("--cb 4 --quiet --save_resume -f vw.model")

# model learn
for data in train_data:
    # function converts data to vw ready data
    learn_example = create_training_sample(data)

    # Here we do the actual learning.
    vw.learn(learn_example)
vw.finish()

vw.save(f"{model_dir_test}/vw.model")
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-d1cf34140f60> in <module>
----> 1 vw.save(f"{model_dir_test}/vw.model")

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vowpalwabbit/pyvw.py in save(self, filename)
    624     def save(self, filename):
    625         """save model to disk"""
--> 626         pylibvw.vw.save(self, filename)
    627 
    628     def finish(self):

RuntimeError: can't open: s3://ddna-working-dev/vw/model/vw.model.writing, errno = No such file or directory
```

Any idea how to save this properly?

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting suggests that the directory you are trying to save the file to does not already exist. I would suggest including the following:

```
import os
os.mkdir(model_dir_test)
```

before you call vw.save() to create the directory.

Comment: This doesn't work for S3. I already made a bucket under `s3://BUCKET/vw/model/` but it adds the `.writing` part which I am not sure of.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the work around is saving the model locally, then uploading that into s3.

Answer (score 0):

`s3://ddna-working-dev/vw/model` is not part of the standard filesystem. VW is just using an `open` call to try and open the file for writing and my guess is that the open call does not understand the `s3://` protocol.

See [here for open call](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/11e2d50e562ae43d60ce19dc33f2715a9805c18b/vowpalwabbit/io/io_adapter.cc#L299):

```
_file_descriptor = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_LARGEFILE | O_TRUNC, 0666);
```